# GCC reporting unrelated errors for include

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, enet

I've added a new file to a project:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include "enet/enet.h" //the problem
typedef struct Player
{
    ENetPeer * peer; //requires problematic include
    //void * peer; //works, since no include required
} Player;
const struct Player playerEmpty;
#endif //PLAYER_H
```

If the `include` is present, I get reams of `error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant` in unrelated files. If I remove the `include` and use `void * peer` instead, all is well. The enet library is included in a source file elsewhere, and works fine. I am using enet 1.3.13 (latest) and its header guards appear to be in place. This is under gcc 4.9.2.

**For the record** the errors are occurring in `Point.h`:

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <stdint.h>

#define X 0
#define Y 1
#define Z 2

typedef  int16_t  int16_Point2[2];
typedef  int32_t  int32_Point2[2];
typedef uint16_t uint16_Point2[2];
typedef uint32_t uint32_Point2[2];

typedef  int16_t  int16_Point3[3];
typedef  int32_t  int32_Point3[3];
typedef uint16_t uint16_Point3[3];
typedef uint32_t uint32_Point3[3];

#endif //POINT_H
```

I'm sure it's something simple - any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single-letter macro names is a good idea in general. They might very easily replace the letters in unexpected locations (note: Macros are actually textual replacement before the actual compilation phases).

You wrote the error is occuring in Point.h. I do not think they actually *occur*, but are only *reported* here. C is notoriously bad to detect grammar errors where they actually are. Check the file which includes Point.h

Note: `const struct Player playerEmpty;` in a header is also likely unwanted, as that will create an object with external linkage in every compilation unit. This is different from C++: in C, there are actually no constants, but only *constant variables*: `const` is just a promise by the programmer the variable will never be changed once initialized. Even worse: you do not assign it a value, thus making it effectively `0` - global variables are initialized to all bits 0. I'm quite sure this in not intended.

**Update:**

If that is for points, how about:

```
typedef union __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
    struct {
        int16_t x,y,z;
    };    // anonymous union field (C99)
    int16_t vec[3];
} int16_Point3;

...

// usage:
int16_Point3 point = (int16_Point3){ .x = 5, .y = 3 }; // compound literal
point.z = point.x + point.vec[1]; // other word for point.y
```

to get rid of the `#define`s and getting proper syntax.

Note `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` is gcc-specific to avoid padding bytes between struct fields. That is non-standard, but other compilers often have similar features (e.g. `pragma`). It is required to have identical layout for the struct and the array.

That might be more readable than the indexing. Note that *anonymous struct and union fields* are standard.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, re struct empties, noted - the purpose in fact is for them to be 0 -- they are used either as failure value for a struct-returning collection, or to reset other struct instances where necessary, without memsetting zero - I find this more intuitive to read.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: Note that this generates memory reads in C, as they are not like constants in C++! In C, it is better (and common practice to use `#define`s, as that allows the compiler to optimize much better. If you still insist on using variables, the correct way would either be to declare this `static` (allthough in a header), or - the correct way: have an 'extern' declaration in the header and the actual definition in a `.c` file. In any case, I strongly recommend to explicitly initialize the value (most compilers complain about a missing initializer for a `const` variable). ...

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: ... - Just a well-meant hint from an experienced long time C (and other languages) developer.

Comment: Point taken -- I will look at these (and your comments, properly) soon, and address, just not right now.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: I updated my answer (that's how I did something similar myself once). you might find that interesting - if my assumption is correct.

Comment: Appreciate this but the indexing isn't (primarily) for my codebase, it's for one of datenwolf's libraries, linmath. So changing the data structures is not an option. And array indexing is far better on multiple-dimension structures, IME, because it allows natural iteration. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: Ok. Regarding indexing: you might have overlooked that's the reason I made that a union. So you can use both: struct-notation or index. Never mind!

Comment: I did overlook that. :) Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was single-character `#define`s. NEVER do this.

I'd been using `X`, `Y` and `Z` for several months, but never had problems till my inclusion of `Player.h`, today, which must have finally - in a roundabout way - triggered some problems in the preprocessor / compiler. Removing these returned compilation to (a semblance of) normality.

Thanks to those who helped in the comments.